# Using one query as login using Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to use this query to log a user into an application using Postgresql database.

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE users.username = 'somename'
AND users.pswd = md5(CONCAT('password','select users.salt from users where users.username = 'somename'))

SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE users.username = 'somename'
AND users.pswd = md5(CONCAT('password','(select users.salt from users where users.username = 'somename' )'))
```

Both of these options return an error at the second somename. There seems to be an issue with the quotation marks.  I have tried using double quotation marks also.

Any one know the correct syntax for this? thanks.

Comment: Please don't use md5 to hash passwords, it's horribly easy to break.

Comment: Is postgresql crypt() gen_salt() considered secure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax error is because you're putting your sub-query in quotes, and then trying to nest more quotes inside that. What you were trying for was this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE users.username = 'somename' 
 AND users.pswd = md5(CONCAT('password',(select users.salt from users where users.username = 'somename' )))
```

However, you don't actually need the sub-query at all, since the salt is in the row the where clause is testing, so this should work fine:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE users.username = 'somename' 
  AND users.pswd = md5(CONCAT('password',users.salt))
```

Comment: Thanks. Sometimes the obvious escapes us.